# Getting updated variable outside IBAction swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a hard time, finding out how to get the updates `facebookProfileUrl` so that I can put an image in my imageview in the cell. As you can see in the code I have made an instance with the var facebookProfileUrl at the top of my page. At the bottom of the code, you can see that if facebookProfileUrl is empty, it will say so - and that's what this code is doing. Even though I am changing facebookProfileUrl in the middle of the code, nothing happens. What can I do to fix this?

```
var facebookProfileUrl = "" // THIS IS BEFORE viewDidLoad



@IBAction func addToFeed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
    if(accessToken != nil) //should be != nil
    {
        let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
        req.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if(error == nil)
            {
                let userId: String? = result.valueForKey("id") as? String
                let userID = userId
                self.facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large" // HERE I AM CHANGING THE VARIABLE

                let feed = Sweet(content: feedContent, addedByUser: name!, profilePhoto: self.facebookProfileUrl)
                let feedRef = self.dbRef.child(feedContent.lowercaseString)

                feedRef.setValue(feed.toAnyObject())

            }
            else
            {
                print("error \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
}





override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:updateTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! updateTableViewCell


    let update = updates[indexPath.row]


    cell.nameLabel.text = update.addedByUser
    cell.updateLabel.text = update.content


    if (facebookProfileUrl != "") {
        if let url = NSURL(string: facebookProfileUrl) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                cell.picView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Empty facebookProfileUrl") // THIS ONE IS PRINTED
    }



    return cell
}
```

Comment: Call reloadData() on the table inside your completion handler.

Comment: How will that make me access the updated facebookProfileUrl outside the action? :)

Comment: req.startWithCompletionHandler is asynchronous and calls its completion AFTER cellForRowAtIndexPath even though you called the function first. Your code will not sit and wait for your network request to complete. Calling reloadData() will trigger cellForRowAtIndexPath again after the value has been set in the closure.

Comment: That makes sence! Should I do this: self.facebookProfileUrl.reloadData() after it has been updated?

Comment: @Dare can you please tell me where I should use reloadData() and what I need to reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `self.tableView.reloadData()` in the completion block (I'd recommend as the last line in the if error == nil condition)

As mentioned above, this is an asynchronous call, meaning that the code within that block `req.startWithCompletionHandler({ ... })` will be called AFTER the server responds. By this point, it's likely that the tableView has already loaded its data (in other words cellForRowAtIndexPath has been called for all cells currently on the screen).

Be careful though! I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish and I haven't seen all of your code, but the way you doing this, all cells will have the same url. It's tough to recommend a better way to do this without more information, but beware.

Comment: Also, generally Swift style does not include parenthesis for if statements. This may be deprecated in the future, as with C style for loops. I put this as a comment because it is more of an opinion/advice than answer

Comment: That is great advice and a great explination! My code is way more than that and after adding the code in the last line of the if error part, of the completion block nothing is changed :( It is really bugging me!

Comment: It was a complete different error.. the id I was trying to get was an optional, that was why the photo wouldnt show :) Thanks for your time and sorry I wasted it!